# SQL table not saving in mysql folder as .sql but as .ibd

Tags: php, mysql

this is my coding:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users( user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, user_first VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, user_last VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, user_email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, user_uid VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, user_pwd VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(user_id), UNIQUE(user_email))
```

However, when I enter my MYSQL folder on my network and enter the data file, it shows the file but stored it as users.ibd and users.from, instead of users.sql. How do I solve this issue?
Thank you,

Comment: really not clear how you are running the querry, or the problem

Comment: **Why** do you expect `sql` extension? Where did this idea come from?

Comment: sql-server <> mysql

Comment: @PM77-1 because my teacher wants us to access a file that has the SQL coding on it later?

Comment: How MySQL is storing data internally is not an issue for you. you should NEVER interact with its internal files, all access should be through one of the API's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL databases are not stored in .sql format, in this case, I suppose your using InnoDB which will save as .ibd file. If you want the mysql file, you can do this in multiple ways:

One way to install/upload Adminer (https://www.adminer.org/) or PhpMyadmin to your server, from there you can access your databases and do multiple tasks, such as exporting, importing, creating rows, tables, etc. What you want here is to export the database as an SQL file.

Another way is to use the mysqldump command in the terminal. You can run something like `mysqldump -u{user} -p {database} > {filename}.sql` Where {user} is your database username, {database} is the name of the database. You will then be prompted to enter your password. This will output the database schema and data in the sql file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: hello, I am using PhpMyadmin?

Comment: In this case, you can log in to phpMyAdmin, find your database and click on it to "select" it. In the right section of the page, you will see tabs, one should be "export". From this tab, you can select the options and then export the database.